# Xposed - Ignoring touch on certain point

Tags: android, touch, screen, xposed-framework

I wanted to know if it is possible to ignore certain touch on defined points via Xposed (even if there is no actual module, would it be possible ?) ?

Comment: Do you need to ignore a touch event within an application or overall? I mean, do you want to filter based on coordinates or elements touched?

Comment: Based on coordinates... BTW, I don't need it anymore... Should I delete the question ?

Comment: I have android 5.1.1, need to ignore for all apps, any solution?

Comment: @bychance Unfortunately, I have not found one. Sorry.